# Where I release this object.Please help me?

Tags: iphone

This is my sample code....i am creating the class object as NSDictionary.Here it shows the leak,Where i release that object it's not right place to release this object?
How can i release this object.
TanX in advance.

```
     NSDictionary *locationDictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer    alloc]deserializeAsDictionary:webresponse error:nil];

NSArray *placemarkArray = [locationDictionary valueForKey:@"Placemark"];

NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [placemarkArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSDictionary *pointDictionary = [tempDictionary valueForKey:@"Point"];

NSArray *coordinateArray = [pointDictionary valueForKey:@"coordinates"];
NSNumber *numberLongitude = [coordinateArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *numberLatitude  = [coordinateArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CJSONDeserializer class has convenient constructor. So use that.

```
CJSONDeserializer *jsonDeserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
```

The deserialize with that object.

```
NSDictionary *locationDictionary = [jsonDeserializer deserializeAsDictionary:webresponse error:nil];
```

So you need not to release that.

Comment: +1 on the constructor with no alloc - then it's autoreleased.  You would only call retain if you need to hold it beyond the lifetime of that function ...

Answer (score 1):

You are calling alloc on the CJSONDeserializer so you own it.  When you are done with it, you need to release it.  I don't see you calling release on it.

The rest of the variable are obtained by not calling alloc, copy, new or mutableCopy so you don't own them.  They have been auto released.  That's the convention.

This is a must read:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

**Specifically, the rules:**

**You own any object you create**
You create an object using a method whose name begins with *“alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”* (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

**You can take ownership of an object using retain**
A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received in, and that method may also safely return the object to its invoker. You use retain in two situations: (1) In the implementation of an accessor method or an init method, to take ownership of an object you want to store as a property value; and (2) To prevent an object from being invalidated as a side-effect of some other operation (as explained in “Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using”).

**When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own**
You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message or an autorelease message. In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as “releasing” an object.

**You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**
This is just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated explicitly.

Comment: TanX for sending reply.I am using that also but still it shows leak.Any alternative way to release that.

Comment: if you put the line of code [locationDictionary release] at the end of your sample code and you still show a memory leak, then the leak is not on the code you posted.

Comment: I don't see you releasing what you alloced.  Can you update your code with the release call?  Perhaps you should create the deserializer by not calling alloc on it as Goumathi suggested - then it's autoreleased and you only retain if you need it beyond the lifetime of that function ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are just after numberLong. and numberLat. retain just them until your done with them.
And if you no longer need the locationDictionary as a whole you can now [locationDitionary release], but only after retaining or finishing with what you need from it.

Comment: you only need to retain if you need to hold them beyond the lifetime of that function.  autoreleased items will get cleaned up at some point in the future after the current function returns ...

Comment: Very true, The question was vague with regards to how long he needed to keep the coordinateArray around.